# Change Gui.Button skin on click trigger

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have the script below and I'm trying to change the Gui.Skin when a user clicks on the button and remove some "money".

```
// Converted from UnityScript to C# at http://www.M2H.nl/files/js_to_c.php - by Mike Hergaarden
// Do test the code! You usually need to change a few small bits.

using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Shop : MonoBehaviour {
    //variables----------------------------------------
    public bool ShowShop = false;
    public Texture CoinTexture;
    public int Money = 0;
    public GUISkin skin = null;
    public GUISkin bought = null;
    public bool AddButton= false;
    //Items:
    //to add more items just copy this variable and add the item name;

    //code----------------------------------------
    void  Start (){}

    void  Update (){
        if(Money <= 0){
            Money = 0;
        }
    }

    private void OnGUI (){
        GUI.skin = skin;
        if(ShowShop ==true){
            //money{********************-------------------------------------------------------------**************************
            GUI.Button( new Rect(Screen.width/60,Screen.height/35  ,50,50), CoinTexture);
            GUI.Button( new Rect(Screen.width/60+50,Screen.height/35  ,70,50), ""+Money);
            if(AddButton ==true){
                if(GUI.Button( new Rect(Screen.width/60+120,Screen.height/35  ,70,50), "Add")){
                    Money += 100;
                }
            }
            //money}***********************-------------------------------------------------------------------*****************************

            //Items(Shop){
            if(GUI.Button( new Rect(20, 70 , 120, 120), "Buy: 100")){
                if(Money >= 100){
                    Money -= 100;
                }else{
                    Money -=0;
                }
            }
            if(GUI.Button( new Rect(140, 70, 120, 120), "Buy: 200")){
                if(Money >= 200){
                    Money -= 200;
                }else{
                    Money -=0;
                }
            }
            if(GUI.Button( new Rect(260, 70, 120, 120), "Buy: 300")){
                if(Money >= 300){
                    Money -= 300;
                }else{
                    Money -=0;
                }
            }
            if(GUI.Button( new Rect(380, 70, 120, 120), "Buy: 400")){
                if(Money >= 400){
                    Money -= 400;
                }else{
                    Money -=0;
                }
            }
            if(GUI.Button( new Rect(20, 190 , 120, 120), "Buy: 500")){
                if(Money >= 500){
                    Money -= 500;
                }else{
                    Money -=0;
                }
            }
            if(GUI.Button( new Rect(140, 190, 120, 120), "Buy: 600")){
                if(Money >= 600){
                    Money -= 600;
                }else{
                    Money -=0;
                }
            }
            if(GUI.Button( new Rect(260, 190, 120, 120), "Buy: 700")){
                if(Money >= 700){
                    Money -= 700;
                }else{
                    Money -=0;
                }
            }
            if(GUI.Button( new Rect(380, 190, 120, 120), "Buy: 800")){
                if(Money >= 800){
                    Money -= 800;
                }else{
                    Money -=0;
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

This part below works perfectly and it subtracts the money from the user. As you can see in the top of the script I  have `Public GUISkin skin = null` and `Public GUISkin bought = null`.

I would like to change the guiskin from `skin` to `bought` when a person click on a button.

```
if(GUI.Button( new Rect(20, 70 , 120, 120), "Buy: 100")){
    if(Money >= 100){
        Money -= 100;
        this.Skin = bought; // THIS IS WHAT I HAVE TRIED
    }else{
        Money -=0;
    }
}
```

I cant seem to find any way to do this - does anybody have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You may use `GUI.skin = bought;` as "this" represents your component behaviour and not your GUI object this.Skin does not reference current GUI.skin in any ways...

Also setting GUI.skin will change all your GUI draws after this to use the new skin so if you want to change just current pressed button you may change it's style and not the entire GUI skin. There is lots of ways to implement this, if you are skinning all your GUI elements I'd suggest you to approach like this:

1. change your GUI.skin just once when you starts your game/scene to get your personal GUISkin working (an easy way to do this is at the beginning of each OnGUI() but is not the better approach looking for performance);
2. create custom styles on your GUISkin custom styles array;
3. when declaring your GUI elements like GUI.Button pass your desired custom style like GUI.Button(myRect, "myLabel", "myCustomStyleName");
4. when desired a button with 2 states (activated and deactivated) use GUI.Toogle instead of GUI.Button (is way easier to style it).

for more information and a better understanding about skinning read the [manual](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-GUISkin.html) to avoid some troubles as changing entire skin when you want to change just the element style itself.

note that OnGUI() functions are called twice or more per frame and instantiating a new Rect as argument to coordinate each element like `GUI.Button(**new Rect(x,y,w,h)**, "myButton")` can result in low performance issues (and you are also performing mathematics into declarations so may you need use GUILayout or change your coordinates declaration to recalculate just when needed).